# Timeout using python subprocess

Tags: python-3.x

I've got a very strange error.  I load large amounts of data to a PG database using psql.  One function in my code does ALL loads.  One part of my codebase calls the load function, and it works JUST fine.  Another part calls the same function with different data), and the psql subprocess call hangs (timeout has to kill it).  Executing the SAME command from the command line works just fine:

Here is my code:

```
myEnv = os.environ.copy()
myEnv["PGPASSWORD"] = <<db password>>

output = None
output = subprocess.check_output(popenArgs, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, timeout=120, env=myEnv)
```

The timeout error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\Dropbox\Engagements\<Client>\Src\prod_db.py", line 102, in _copyFrom
    output = subprocess.check_output(popenArgs, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, timeout=120, env=myEnv)
  File "C:\Tools\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Tools\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 703, in run
    stderr=stderr)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql.exe" -h <<DB LOCATION>> -p 5432 -d forecast_dev -U forecast -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -AtXwa -c "\copy di_entities_load from C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\copytempdi_entities_load7.csv with csv"' timed out after 120 seconds
```

If I set the PGPASSWORD variable manually in a command line window, and then copy and paste the command in the error to the command line, it runs fine, and quickly, exiting and returning upon completion.

As I said, this code works when called from a different part of my application, to a different table, with different data.

Any idea what would cause this to fail when called from python, while it still works on the command line?

Windows 10 Pro, Py3.5, PG 9.4, pg8000 db module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that I was locking the table prior to the copy, and since the copy runs in a different process, it was seeing a locked table to write to and hanging.